# Polling periodically a REST API

Tags: android, rest, service, threadpool

What should I use if I need to periodically poll a REST api to see if the data in my listView has updated from the server? I though about using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor inside a IntentService but It might be overkill? It has to be done in background and if the task is killed when the Activity that contains the listview is destroy, that'd be great too.

What is the modern way to do this now in 2016?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a SyncAdapter by extending `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter`. This is well documented here:
http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Instead of polling the REST API you can use a BroadcastReceiver to receive messages from the server when the data changes. GCM provides the components you need to make it work. See here: http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html